# Dynamodb requestHandler acception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have found a cryptic exception when running dynamo inserts in the cloud, any help or clues as to how to debug such an error ?

**Background**

The code I am running  :

- Succesfully inserts data into dynamodb when run from my local machines, but
- Fails abruptly due to authentication when running in the cloud in a mapreduce job over EMR.
- Uses a URL endpoint for authentication.

I simply create credentials like so:

```
   client=new DynamoDBClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(
        "XXXX",
        "XXXXXXXXXXX));
   client.setEndpoint("https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
```

**The exception Im getting is below:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: requestHandlers
        at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.init(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:214)
        at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.<init>(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:160)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.STSSessionCredentialsProvider.<init>(STSSessionCredentialsProvider.java:73)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.SessionCredentialsProviderFactory.getSessionCredentialsProvider(SessionCredentialsProviderFactory.java:96)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.setEndpoint(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:857)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.init(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:262)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:181)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:142)
```

Comment: update : it appears that there is an old version of aws-sdk, 1.1.1 that is included in the EMR nodes !  This might be causing a class versioning conflict.   Im not sure the best way to resolve but am considering some options and running tests now.

Answer (score 2):

The "real" answer here, is that, dynamodb clients which don't match up with the latest or current versions can exhibit odd reflection / class loading error when we attempt to use them in a modern environment.

- AWS jars exist on the class path of older EMR AMI instances can conflict with proper (latest) AWS jars used by hadoop job which invokes a non-EMR service (i.e. such as dynamodb, in our case).

On my older AMI instance, I simply issued:

```
mv $HOME/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.1.1.jar $HOME/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.1.1.jar.old
```

To resolve the issue on a single node cluster.

---

The ROOT cause of this error? was that I was using an older Ruby elastic-mapreduce client, which led to creation of older AMI versions in my EMR cloud, which had obsolete aws-sdk jars on the class path.