# Overriding default hadoop jars in class path

Tags: jar, hadoop, classpath, operator-precedence

I've seen many manifestations of ways to use the user class path as precedent to the hadoop one.  Often times this is done if an m/r job needs a specific version of a library that hadoop coincidentally already uses an older version of (for example jackson's json parser or commons http , etc.)

In any case : I've seen :

```
mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence
mapreduce.task.classpath.first
mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first
```

Which one of these parameters is the *right* one to set in my job configuration, in order to force mappers and reducers to have a class path which puts my user defined `hadoop_classpath` jars BEFORE the hadoop default dependency jars ?

By the way, this is related to this question : 
[Dynamodb requestHandler acception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660441/dynamodb-requesthandler-acception) which I recently have found is due to a jar conflict.

Comment: What version / distribution of hadoop are you using / targetting?

Comment: Well... Ideally I'd like to know how this parameter has changed from version to version if it has... But I beleive our current version is 2.0.23

Comment: 2.0.23? http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/, i guess you mean 0.20.203?

Comment: try: conf.setBoolean(MRJobConfig.MAPREDUCE_JOB_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST, true);

Answer (score 5):

So, assuming you're using 0.20.203, this is handled in the [TaskRunner.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.203.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskRunner.java?view=markup) code as follows:

- The property you're looking for is on line 94 - `mapreduce.user.classpath.first`
- Line 214 is where the call is made to build the list of classpaths, which delegates to a method called `getClassPaths(..)`
- `getClassPaths()` is defined on line 524, and you should be able to see that the configuration property is used to decide on whether your job + dist cache libraries, or the hadoop libraries go on the classpath first

For other versions of hadoop, you're best to check the TaskRunner.java class to confirm the name of the config property after all this is a *"semi hidden config"*:

```
static final String MAPREDUCE_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST =
        "mapreduce.user.classpath.first"; //a semi-hidden config
```

Comment: Unfortunately this feature doesn't exist in [0.20.2](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.2/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskRunner.java?view=markup)...

Comment: @Chris, interesting answer. But why this is hidden (or semi-hidden) at all? any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

As in the latest Hadoop version (2.2+), you should set:

```
    conf.setBoolean(MRJobConfig.MAPREDUCE_JOB_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

These settings work for referencing classes of external jars only in your mapper or reducer tasks. If, however, you are using these in, for example a customized InputFormat, it will fail to load the class. A way to make sure this also works everywhere (in MR2) is exporting this setting when submitting your job:

```
export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the parameter that worked for me on Hadoop Version 0.20.2-cdhu03 is "mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence"

This setting is tested not work on CDH3U3, following answer is from Cloudera team:

```
// JobConf job = new JobConf(getConf(), MyJob.class);
// job.setUserClassesTakesPrecedence(true);
```

http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setUserClassesTakesPrecedence%28boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

In the MapR distribution, the property is "mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence"
http://www.mapr.com/doc/display/MapR/mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Set to true if user wants to set different classpath. (AVRO) </description>
</property>
```

jobConf.setUserClassesTakesPrecedence(true);