# Oozie shell action - running sqoop command and need logging details

Tags: hadoop, workflow, hdfs, oozie, sqoop

I am working with Oozie, shell action and sqoop.

I am using oozie to run many sqoop commands. I have set up a shell action and in that shell I have placed many sqoop commands. Now, shell action is getting triggered and even sqoop is happening.

However, there is no proper logging for sqoop. So I had sqoop command being redirected to the log file. There I am seeing only the following lines.

My code is as follows. Inside the shell script:

```
*
sqoop import  --connect jdbc:mysql://server:3306/test --verbose  --username root --password Password    --append --table People  --m 1 --hive-drop-import-delims  --target-dir  /user/username/20/  --delete-target-dir  >> /tmp/log
*
```

Log details captured:

> Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
>   Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.

How can I get sqoop logs using shell action in Oozie? I need details like how many records loaded/pulled, and usual logging which happens when we run sqoop command on console.

Please find below my jobproperties.xml:

```
*oozie.use.system.libpath=True
credentials={u'hcat': {'xml_name': u'hcat', 'properties': [('hcat.metastore.uri', u'thrift://node:9083'), ('hcat.metastore.principal', u'hive/node@.COM')]}, u'hive2': {'xml_name': u'hive2', 'properties': [('hive2.jdbc.url', 'jdbc:hive2://node.jnj.com:10000/default'), ('hive2.server.principal', 'hive/itsusraedld01.jnj.com@.COM')]}, u'hbase': {'xml_name': u'hbase', 'properties': []}}
nameNode=hdfs://nameservice1
jobTracker=yarnRM
oozie.sqoop.log.level=DEBUG
log4jConfig=debug-log.properties
 oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/share/lib*
```

Comment: `>>` is short for `1>>` which means "redirect stream #1 (STDOUT) to a file" but most logs are coming from stream #2 (STDERR)... therefore you need to `1>> wtf/duh.log 2>> wtf/duh.log`

Comment: BTW, if you don't redirect STDERR, it will show in the YARN logs -cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732#34359732

Comment: Thanks Samson.i did get the std err - however, the issue here is - i am using sqoop within the shell, its not showing sqoop log, its showing me this log - log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/8217-yarn-NODEMANAGER/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/8217-yarn-NODEMANAGER/log4j.properties (Permission denied)  how do i get the sqoop log generated with shell log/stderr

Comment: Your code blocks begin and end with an asterisk (`*`). Are they actually part of the code in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a parameter hinting that Log4J should use a specific properties file, but Sqoop is not instructed to use it (no `-Dlog4j.configuration=...file name without path...` on command line).

OK, let's assume that is is done on purpose (?); the problem is that

- Log4J searchs for a properties file w/ **default** name i.e. `log4j.properties`
- search is done in the directories present in CLASSPATH, stopping on first match
- default CLASSPATH for an Oozie shell is Hadoop JARs, then Hadoop conf dir, then current working dir *(the place where all `<file>` dependencies are dumped along with Oozie JARs)* and all these app/Oozie JARs
- the first match for `log4j.properties` happens to be a file that Log4J cannot open
- thus Log4J does not log anything anywhere (????????)

A possible workaround would be

1. create a custom `log4j.properties` -- cf. 1st example in [that post](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/) to log anything tagged INFO and above *(i.e. INFO, WARN, ERROR but not DEBUG)* to StdOut
2. upload that file to HDFS somewhere, then tell the Oozie Action to download it to the container with a `<file>` element
3. tell the Oozie Action to request that its CLASSPATH starts with current working dir, by setting a property such as `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.task.classpath.first` to `true` *(actual property may depend on your Hadoop version, see [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685949/overriding-default-hadoop-jars-in-class-path) and [that JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2066))*

Note that step 3 is only necessary because of the default name being present elsewhere in the CLASSPATH; if Sqoop was instructed to use a different file with a different name then there would be no ambiguity.